# Gcc compiler runs infinitely compiling Hello World program

Tags: gcc, msys2

I installed gcc compiler using msys2 tool and I can't compile even silmple hello world program. After I execute simple command gcc runs infinitely:

```
$ gcc a.c
```

I can access --help and --version normally. 
I am using 9.1.0 version

Comment: Could you try to run a compile without linking process and say what happens? 

(Try:  $ gcc -c a.c)

Comment: Nothing changes.

Comment: Is it running on a regular linux gcc? Attach your code.